# How to show all when null using coalesce?

Tags: sql, postgresql, jasper-reports

I have been making a report i have a parameter called 
`P{participants}` and `P{age}`.

Im using it like this `P!{participants}` to accept multiple inputs so i can display mulitple records. I tried using this.

```
where (participants in P!{participants} or
 P!{participants} is null) and (age in P!{age} or P!{age} is null
```

Im using this query to display ALL records whenever iI leave the parameter blank but I'm getting errors about my OR clause and sometimes getting no pages.

I think using coalesce is the best way to go but I'm trying it and cant quite get it any help. I'm using postgres and creating a report in iReport to display all records when input is null.

Comment: There is missing close parenthesis at the end other than that logic looks right

Comment: @NathanielPantilanan Did you try to use `$X{}` expression? [Parameterized Queries](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/query/)